# is_error_code_enum<> enumeration must be defined in global namespace only?

Tags: c++, c++11, overloading

I am trying to create my own enum-based error category and want my enum with error codes to be defined inside some namespace. Much to my surprise this prevents the automatic conversion from values of my enum into `std::error_code` (such conversion works if the enum is defined in the global namespace).

```
#include <system_error>

namespace NS { enum class X {a,b,c}; }
using NS::X;

class X_category : public std::error_category
{
public:
    virtual const char *name() const noexcept override { return "X"; }
    virtual std::string message(int ev) const override { return ""; }
};

inline const std::error_category& X_category()
{
    static class X_category c; return c;
}

template<> struct std::is_error_code_enum<X> : public std::true_type{};

inline std::error_code make_error_code(X result)
{
    return std::error_code(static_cast<int>(result), X_category());
}

int main()
{
    std::error_code e = X::a; // does not work !!
}
```

Am I missing something in my code above (related to overloading resolution rules perhaps) to make it work? Or do the enums for `std::is_error_code_enum<>` can only be defined inside a global namespace??

EDIT. My compiler (MSVC2013) does not complain about it but it seems the specialization of std::is_error_code_enum<> must be done inside std namespace. Also I added noexcept keyword on name() method to make the code even more C++11 compliant (MSVC2013 won't understand noexcept, but MSVC2015 will).

EDIT2. According to C++11 14.7.3.2 [temp.expl.spec]:

> An explicit specialization shall be declared in a namespace enclosing the specialized template.

So it is not necessary to put specialization of std::is_error_code_enum<> inside an std namespace. MSVC compiles it correctly but GCC complains which is actually a bug in GCC since GCC acts by old C++03 rules which were more restrictive.

Comment: @juanchopanza All the code is relevant, there are no other errors apart from the one I am asking about (except missing `noexcept` if your compiler supports it) and I have no idea what is MCVE you are asking me to post.

Comment: He's trying to define a custom error_code that interoperates properly with std::error_code. All the code above main() is actually required to set that up.

Comment: @juanchopanza The conversion from X to std::error_code is enabled by specializing std::is_error_code_enum<X> which enables the std::error_code(X) constructor template which calls make_error_code(X) which uses X_category.

Comment: @PowerGamer Fair enough. That makes sense now that you fixed the other errors.

Comment: For future reference: a guide on how to plug into std::error_code: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/outcome/doc/html/motivation/plug_error_code.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The constructor template from `error_code` is indeed considered in overload resolution - you correctly specialized `is_error_code`. The problem is the ADL in this line in the definition of `error_code`s constructor template:

```
*this = make_error_code(__e);
```

**ADL does not consider the global namespace** because `X` was only defined in `NS`, not the global one. [basic.lookup.argdep]/(2.3):

> If `T` is an enumeration type, its associated namespace is the
>   innermost enclosing namespace of its declaration. [..]

The using declaration doesn't change this. [basic.lookup.argdep]/2:

> The sets of namespaces and classes is determined entirely by the types
>   of the function arguments (and the namespace of any template template
>   argument).
>   **Typedef names and *using-declaration*s used to specify the types do not contribute to this set.**

To fix this add your `make_error_code` to NS:

```
namespace NS {
    inline std::error_code make_error_code(X result)
    {
        return std::error_code(static_cast<int>(result), X_category());
    }
}
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0de29e0a300136b8).

Comment: Category is stored inside std::error_code as const-ref so this won't work and will leave a dangling reference to the temporary X_category()

Comment: But cppreference gives that one constructor delegates to another via `error_code(0, std::system_category())`, so that's nonsense. How did you conclude that, anyway?

Comment: std::system_category() is a function that returns a reference, it is not constructing a temporary.

Comment: I see now your code contains a reference to the category. Did you edit this? (or was I just missing it before?)

Comment: @ReDucTor My bad concerning `system_error`. And now, I never edited this post.-

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that most of that setup code needs to be inside a namespace. This code compiles and runs for me in ideone:

```
#include <system_error>
#include <iostream>

namespace NS {
    enum X {a,b,c};

    class X_category : public std::error_category
    {
    public:
        virtual const char *name() const noexcept override { return "X"; }
        virtual std::string message(int ev) const override { return "M"; }
    };

    inline std::error_code make_error_code(X result)
    {
        return std::error_code(static_cast<int>(result), X_category());
    }
}

namespace std {
    template<> struct is_error_code_enum<NS::X> : public true_type{};
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << NS::X::a;
    std::error_code e = NS::X::a;
    std::cout << e.value();
}
```

Unfortunately I still can't make much sense out of system_error, so I can't explain why, for instance, using an enum class instead of just a plain enum gives me an unspecified runtime error.

Comment: I knew the problem was in overload resolution which I must confess did not have time to study in details. Thanks for suggesting a solution (which Columbo has also explained). BTW, there must be a single instance of class X_category because categories are compared by address. So you can't create new instances every time your make_error_code() is called.

Comment: Category is stored inside std::error_code as const-ref so this won't work and will leave a dangling reference to the temporary X_category()